# LWC button SendMail Quickaction does not work in Case Lightning Record page

Tags: email, case, lightning-quickaction, navigationmixin.navigate, lightningnavigation

I follow this step:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_email
for creating a button of triggering a SendMail quickaction with LWC.
When I add the button on Contact and Account Lightning record page, it works perfectly but does not work in Case Lightning record page where I need it.

Please help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I encounter the same issue, did you find a solution for it?

Comment: No! I am still looking for the solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow this approach https://www.salesforcelwc.in/send-email-lwc.html as the approach you have mentioned ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_email) fails for case and works only for contact & account object.

Please upvote if it works for you it did for me when I faced same issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/198623)